# Remove start of filenames Bat file

Tags: batch-file, rename

[image]

Hi guys,

I am looking for a batch file I can run that will search for every file within that folder (not subfolders) and rename each file's string up, removing the first part of the string until after the " - "
See the attached image for an example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of using a wild card with string substitution.  It is non greedy so you can make it remove everything from the file name up to the first time it finds {space hyphen space}.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /A-D-H "* - *.*" 2^>nul') do (
    set "string=%%G"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    SET "end=!string:* - =!"
    rename "%%G" "!end!"
    endlocal
)
```

@Compo showed you how to use `FINDSTR` to not parse files with a specific extension. Here is how you can utilize the `FOR` command modifiers with a comparison to do the same.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /A-D-H "* - *.*" 2^>nul') do (
    IF /I NOT "%%~xG"==".msg" ( 
        set "string=%%G"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        SET "end=!string:* - =!"
        rename "%%G" "!end!"
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Comment: that's amazing!
Could you please give me a bit of a rundown on how it works? Please and thankyou!
Below was as far as I had gotten before you answered (probably all wrong):
`setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b %cd%') do (
echo %%f
)
pause`

Comment: @JimmyWilliams are you aware that if this solved your problem that you should be accepting the answer as you clearly stated in a comment that it worked? Also, why ask another question as you did pretty much repeating the requirement but excluding `.Msg` files. If your question here was clear to begin with, it would have been answered as such.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Squashman's answer, just not using `delayedexpansion` in this version. Amended to include the exclusion of `.msg` file extensions.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "* - *.*"') do if /i not "%%~xi" == ".msg" set "file=%%~i" && call :ren
goto :eof
:ren
ren "%file%" "%file:*- =%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative, it uses the same method of removing all content up to and including the first instance of space hyphen space, as the already existing answers, but a different method of identifying those files, i.e. `where.exe`:

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('(Set PATHEXT^=^) ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe
 "%~dp0.":"?* - ?*" 2^>NUL') Do (Set "FileName=%%~nxG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Ren "%%G" "!FileName:* - =!" & EndLocal)
```

And, as an extension of your [subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66919108), *(now closed)*, the following example uses `findstr.exe` to exclude any files which carry a `.msg` extension:

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('(Set PATHEXT^=^) ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe
 "%~dp0.":"?* - ?*" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIV ".msg"'
) Do (Set "FileName=%%~nxG" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Ren "%%G" "!FileName:* - =!" & EndLocal)
```

Also, as there was a discrepancy between the body text and the title of your closed question, if you wanted to only rename the `.msg` files, and leave the others untouched, then:

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('(Set PATHEXT^=^) ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe
 "%~dp0.":"?* - ?*.msg" 2^>NUL') Do (Set "FileName=%%~nxG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Ren "%%G" "!FileName:* - =!" & EndLocal)
```